# IndexOutOfRange/ System.FormatException in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with checkbox in my codebehind page. The functionality is that I need to select the records to be deleted using checkbox and click the delete button. I use the below code to do that.. But when I select the last row it does not get deleted. Instead it throws IndexOutOfRange/ System.FormatException ..

The error is thrown at this line

```
  CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk");


       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         {
             CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chk");
             if (chkb.Checked == true)
             {
                 string name = gvAll.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
                 if (!(name.Equals(System.DBNull.Value)))
                 {
                     a.delete(name);
                 }
             }
         }
```

It's an urgent issue. Please help..

Comment: a is an object to another class..

Answer (score 1):

How about a foreach?

```
     foreach(GridViewRow row in gvAll.Rows)
     { 
         CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chk"); 
         if (chkb.Checked == true) 
         { 
             string name = row.Cells[3].Text; 
             if (!(name.Equals(System.DBNull.Value))) 
             { 
                 a.delete(name); 
             } 
         } 
     }
```